# How to Ignore route for a specific View folder or a sepecific cshtml file in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to ignore the routing when browse a specific page in the Views folder, I unsuccessfully attempted that by use :

```
        routes.RouteExistingFiles = false;
    routes.IgnoreRoute("Views/NoMove/specificPage.cshtml");
```

But above didn't work, because the Internet browser ask me to download the file and it doesn't open/process it the page!

What is the problem please, and How to fix it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to add an entry in your web.config.

Check the `appSettings` section

add this (or update)

```
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />
```

The entry is probably there already, so just update the value from false to true.

They are 2 web.config files though .. one in the root of your app and another in the views folder .. you may need to add/update the entry on both.

The default value (`false`) prevents `*.cshtml` and `*.vbhtml` files from being accessed directly from the browser.

Comment: I am confused. Sorry. OP is facing issue in cshtml and this post is saying to add webpages !!! Can you explain it...a bit?

Comment: @PKKG the reason why the runtime doesn't process the pages (*cshtml) is the setting i explained in my answer.