# Displaying Charts Inside a Web Page with Chart Helper

Tags: c#, razor

I have been following the tutorial found here [Displaying Data in a Chart with ASP.NET Web Pages (Razor)](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/data/7-displaying-data-in-a-chart)

I tried the section titled **Displaying Charts Inside a Web Page** with the code

```
<img src="_DrawChart.cshtml" />
```

but I got the exception

```
A public action method '_DrawChart.cshtml' was not found on controller 'NonContractual.Areas.Reports.Controllers.HomeController'.
```

Aha! I thought.  I need to ignore the route, so in `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes` I added

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*charting}", new { charting = @"(.*/)?_DrawChart.cshtml(/.*)?" });
```

which is a simple adaptation of the usual one for favicon.  But I still got the same exception.

A bit more digging and trial and error led me to add the whole route for ignoring

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("Reports/Home/_DrawChart.cshtml");
```

but still I get the same exception.  So then I found this question/answer [How to Ignore route for a specific View folder or a sepecific cshtml file in ASP.NET MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18682143/how-to-ignore-route-for-a-specific-view-folder-or-a-sepecific-cshtml-file-in-asp) so I dutifully changed the web.config files and now I get the exception

```
Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' was thrown.
```

And anyway, I don't like the idea of allowing direct access to the `.cshtml` files.

My `_DrawChart.cshtml` file simply contains the code from the tutorial

```
@{
var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
    .AddTitle("Chart Title")
    .AddSeries(
        name: "Employee",
        xValue: new[] { "Peter", "Andrew", "Julie", "Mary", "Dave" },
        yValues: new[] { "2", "6", "4", "5", "3" })
    .Write();
}
```

So my question is, how can I use a `.cshtml` file containing chart drawing code as the `src` for an `img` tag in a .NET web application?

By the way, I can get charts displayed by calling a method on the controller

```
<img src="@Url.Action("DrawPieChart", "Home")" />
```

a techique I discovered here [MVC3, Razor and MS Chart Controls in .NET 4](http://www.jayway.com/2011/12/11/mvc3-razor-and-ms-charting-tool-net-4/)

There is remarkably little information out there on using Charts.